# How do you get the next page of twitter results using the Twitter OAuth API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the twitter oath API and I get the first page of results for my search query.  But I want to get all pages, so how do I iterate using the API to get the next page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter has been removing support for pagination from their API, in favor of query params that specify search bounds. Here's the relevant snippet from their blog:

"All methods currently supporting cursoring or usage of since_id and max_id will remove support for "classic" pagination through the "page" parameters. See [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) for more information."

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-housekeeping

Comment: There's not much sample code about (and the code I've written uses the Temboo SDK, which heavily wraps the Twitter API). Here's what a sample URL would look like though: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=raccoons&since_id=123455